# Nothing happens after instantiate Canvas on android

Tags: java, android

I don't know what is happening with `Canvas`:

```
// @param String source
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(source);

Log.i("output", "This message will be printed!");

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

Log.i("output", "This message will NOT be printed, canvas stop all!");
```

After instantiate `Canvas`, nothing is being printed and I cannot run any code, but the application does not close.

► Run (output after the call):

> *D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 131K, 4% free 11360K/11783K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 15ms*
>
> *D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 22, 33856, 1157696*
>
> *D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 24, 36864, 1120832*

Comment: But you don't pass canvas anywhere. Where it will draw? Also, what is the size of your `Bitmap`? Maybe it's just too big.

Comment: @Ekalips My image is smaller only for test on emulator, I instanced Canvas for use its instance after if I need, is this the problem? thank u!

Comment: are you sure, that second Log.d isn't printed? After passing of time? If it doesn't throw exception, then it must reach that point. Maybe you should try to use debugger to ensure, that `Bitmap` was loaded successfully.

Comment: @Ekalips You helped me when said: "Where it will draw?", I changed to: canvas = new Canvas(); canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null); Thank u for support, sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: Glad that I could help you)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another bitmap with the properties of bmp and pass that to the canvas:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(source);
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
```